# Angular-HttpClient: Map object to array properties

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I am calling an API which returns me a JSON Object. I need to map this object to an array.

Below is my code but after API call neither am getting any response nor any error.

```
export class Features {
  MenuId: number;
  MenuName: string;
  Description: string;
  RoutePath: string;
}

featureList: Features[] = [];
 constructor(private http: HttpClient)

 getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(userID: number) { debugger;       
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID)     
      .pipe(
      map(
        (data: any[]) => {
        debugger;
        this.featureList = data;
        //return true;
      }), catchError(error => {
        debugger;
        return throwError('Something went wrong!')
      })
    );
 }
```

Also tried below code but its giving me an error :

> Type object is not assignable to type 'any[]'

```
 featureList: Array<any> = [];

 getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(userID: number) { debugger;  
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          debugger;
          this.featureList = data;            
      });
 }
```

**Edit :**

```
 return this.http.get<Array<Features>>(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID)   
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          debugger;
          //this.featureList = data;  
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from`.map()`. You should return `this.featureList` from service

```
getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(userID: number) { debugger;       
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID)     
      .pipe(
      map(
        (data: any[]) => {
        debugger;
       return this.featureList = data;
      }), catchError(error => {
        debugger;
        return throwError('Something went wrong!')
      })
    );
 }
```

EDIT

Also `map` seems unnecessary in your code, because you are not manipulating anything inside over there. You may take off that and keep `catchError` to handle errors.

```
getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(userID: number) {       
    return this.http.get(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID)     
      .pipe(
           catchError(error => {
            return throwError('Something went wrong!')
      })
    );
 }
```

And in your component

```
this.service.getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(id)
      .subscribe(data => { this.featureList = data })
```

Comment: What does `http.get()` return. Is it returning any data? Can you check in network tab?

Comment: not calling api, but with second code mentioned in question its calling api and returning json with same api url..

Comment: should it be a http call instead on httpclient in case to map object?

Comment: No that should not matter. Http was used in earlier versions of angular/ Both function the same.

Comment: @SunilKumar Just remove this featureList property of your service. It's useless and wrong. And remove that map(), which is incorrect, and wouldn't do anything useful if it was made correct. And that catchError, which hides the existing error behind another one which doesn't say anything useful. Define a type for the actual type of the elements instead of using any. Then all you need is: `return this.http.get<Array<TheActualTypeOfTheElements>>(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID);`

Comment: should I try return this.http.get<Array<Features>>(this.myAppUrl + "api/Employee/GetMenusByUID/" + userID);?? @JBNizet

Comment: Yes As said by @JBNizet, map seems unnecessary, because you are not manipulating anything inside over there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said. Except of course the interface should be probably be named `Feature` and not `Features`: an instance of that class is **one** feature.

Comment: I am unable to call api without subscribe @JBNizet, I have also added this in question(in edit), still there how to map??

Comment: The service must **not** subscribe. The component calling the service must do that. Your code shows that the response you get **is** the array you want. So there's nothing to map.

Comment: You should subscribe inside your component instead 

`this.service.getFeatureListByLoggedInUser(id).subscribe(data => { this.featureList = data })`